# First 10 terms of a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

My problem:

> Give the first 10 terms of $f(5,b)$ in the recursive sequence defined by
>   \begin{equation}
> f(a,b) = \begin{cases}
>     -2 & \text{if } b = 0\\
>     3 & \text{if } b = 1\\
>     1 & \text{if } b = 2\\
>     f(f(b+2, b-3), b-1)-a & \text{if } b \geq 3\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

I think the answer may be  -4, -9, -14, -19, -24, -29, -34, -39, -44, -49. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Just do it.  They give you the first three and a formula to find all the rest so .... what's your question.

Comment: $f(5,0) = -2$, $f(5,1) = 3$, $f(5,2)=1$.  And $f(5,3)=f(f(5,0),2) - 5=f(-2,2)-5=1-5=-4$.  What do you think the rest are?

Comment: Thank you fleablood this helps a ton. Also im sorry everyone guess I should've been more clear about my question. I was not sure how to apply the formula.

Comment: @fleablood so I think I figured out how this works. at first I kept getting -4 for my answers but then I realized I was not carrying the -5 each step I did when b=3. Would my answer be -4, -9, -14, -19, -24, -29, -34, -39, -44, -49?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(a,3)=f(f(5,0),2)-a=-a+1$

$f(a,4)=f(f(6,1),3)-a=f(3,3)-a=-a-2$

$f(a,5)=f(f(7,2),4)-a=f(1,4)-a=-a-3$

$f(a,6)=f(f(8,3),5)-a=f(-7,5)-a=-a+4$

$f(a,7)=f(f(9,4),6)-a=f(-11,6)-a=-a+15$

$f(a,8)=f(f(10,5),7)-a=f(-13,7)-a=-a+28$

$f(a,9)=f(f(11,6),8)-a=f(-7,8)-a=-a+35$

$f(a,10)=f(f(12,7),9)-a=f(3,9)-a=-a+32$

$f(a,11)=f(f(13,8),10)-a=f(15,10)-a=-a+17$

$f(a,12)=f(f(14,9),11)-a=f(21,11)-a=-a-4$

So substituting $a=5$ we get:

$f(5,0)=-2; f(5,1)=3; f(5,2)=1; f(5,3)=-4$

$f(5,4)=-7,f(5,5)=-8,f(5,6)=-1,f(5,7)=10$

$f(5,8)=23,f(5,9)=30,f(5,10)=27,f(5,11)=12,f(5,12)=-9$